# Laravel relationship null foreign key fetching

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1, foreign-key-relationship

Since a team_id is optional in my tickets table, i've set it to be nullable but still is a foreign key to teams table, but when i try to fetch multiple rows of ticket with relationship to teams table, tickets that has team_id returns properly but tickets that has null team_id breaks the program and returns this error "Trying to get property of non-object".

Migration:

```
Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('team_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
});

Schema::table('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('team_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('teams');
});
```

Ticket model

```
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Team', 'team_id', 'id');
}
```

Team model

```
public function tickets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Ticket', 'id', 'team_id');
}
```

Ticket controller

```
$tickets = Ticket::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();

foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
   var_dump($ticket->team->name);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will, because `$ticket->team` doesn't exist for rows where `team_id` is null.

You could do this

```
foreach ($tickets as $ticket) {
    if($ticket->team){
        var_dump($ticket->team->name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for idea, the isset should be remove thou, coz technically $ticket->team is set, it just had a value of null.

Comment: i wasn't sure if laravel returned anything if there was no relation, accepted the edit. Glad it pushed you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key is a foreign key under all conditions, there is no way to implement a conditional foreign key constraint that'll look up to a table only when it is not null. Best case (or rather, worst case), you can add a NULL value to the primary key table it is looking up to.